# Misunderstanding about direct products of groups

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm making a revision of basic abstract algebra and I'm confused about internal weak direct products of groups. I'm reading Hungerford's abstract algebra book and I think two theorems of this book are contradictory.

[image]

So if $G$ is the direct product of the normal subgroups $N$ and $K$, then the product $nk$, where $n\in N$ and $k\in K$, isn't unique, because $nk=kn$.

In the chapter 8 the author says:

[image]

Why these theorems aren't contraditory with each other?

Thanks

Comment: It just means the product of $n$ and $k$ in G, not the product in the direct product of $N$ and $K$.

Comment: @sebigu I'm sorry, but I didn't follow you. $G$ IS the direct product of $N$ and $K$.

Comment: @sebigu I got it!!! Thank you!!!

Comment: @sebigu Would you like to make an answer? so that I could upvote you.

Comment: Did it, sorry for being so late.

Answer (score 1):

Ordered products are unique, while unordered products are not unique.  In the (external) direct product $G\times H$, for example, we have $(g,1)\cdot(1,h) = (1,h)\cdot (g,1)$.

If you want unordered products to be unique, you should study the [free product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_product), not the direct product.

Answer (score 0):

It means the Product $nk$ of $n$ and $k$ in $G$, not the product in the direct Product of $N$ and $K$.